# How to create partitions from one impala table to another

Tags: database, cloudera, impala

I want to clone an impala table called 'blah' in our database for test purposes (so I don't accidentally delete something I shouldn't).  However, table 'blah' has partitions and it doesn't seem like the command I'm running is doing the trick.  Can someone tell me any tricks to have the partitions automatically created/mimicked in the new table or do I need to manually create the partitions in my new table?

The cmd I'm using is:

```
CREATE TABLE blah_copy LIKE blah
INSERT INTO TABLE blah_copy SELECT * FROM blah
```

It looks to create the table for me when I run because they have the same number of columns

```
desc blah
desc blah_copy
```

However, when I try to copy the data (the insert statement above), it tells me

```
ERROR: AnalysisException: Not enough partition columns mentioned in query. Missing columns are: www, xxx, yyy, zzz.
```

Looking at the [cloudera documentation](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/archive/impala/2-x/2-0-x/topics/impala_create_table.html), it says:

> If the original table is partitioned, the new table inherits the same
>   partition key columns. Because the new table is initially empty, it
>   does not inherit the actual partitions that exist in the original one.
>   To create partitions in the new table, insert data or issue ALTER
>   TABLE ... ADD PARTITION statements.

So that's where I'm at right now.  Thanks in advance for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 4):

If you have latest impala version you could do

```
create table blah_copy partitioned by (column_x, column_y, column_z) as select * from blah;
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to add a `PARTITION (column)` to your insert query

```
INSERT INTO TABLE blah_copy PARTITION (column) 
SELECT * FROM blah
```

Answer (score 2):

1. set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict
2. CREATE TABLE blah_copy LIKE blah;
3. INSERT INTO TABLE blah_copy partition(wName,xName,yName,zName) SELECT * FROM blah;